# How to get corners using GPUImageHarrisCornerDetectionFilter

Tags: ios, swift2, gpuimage

I am trying to get the corner points from a still image using `GPUImageHarrisCornerDetectionFilter`.

I have looked at the example code from the project, I have looked at the documentation, and I have looked at this post that is about the same thing: 
[GPUImage Harris Corner Detection on an existing UIImage gives a black screen output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183271/gpuimage-harris-corner-detection-on-an-existing-uiimage-gives-a-black-screen-out/20183508)

But I can't make it work - and I have a hard time understanding how this is supposed to work with still images.

What I have at this point is this:

```
func harrisCorners() -> [CGPoint] {
    var points = [CGPoint]()

    let stillImageSource: GPUImagePicture = GPUImagePicture(image: self.image)
    let filter = GPUImageHarrisCornerDetectionFilter()

    filter.cornersDetectedBlock = { (cornerArray:UnsafeMutablePointer<GLfloat>, cornersDetected:UInt, frameTime:CMTime) in
        for index in 0..<Int(cornersDetected) {
            points.append(CGPoint(x:CGFloat(cornerArray[index * 2]), y:CGFloat(cornerArray[(index * 2) + 1])))
        }
    }

    filter.forceProcessingAtSize(self.image.size)
    stillImageSource.addTarget(filter)
    stillImageSource.processImage()

    return points
}
```

This function always returns `[]` so it's obviously not working.

An interesting detail - I compiled the FilterShowcaseSwift project from GPUImage examples, and the filter fails to find very clear corners, like on a sheet of paper on a black background.

Comment: As to the lack of finding clear corners, the Harris corner detector isn't scale-invariant, so the higher resolution the image, the sharper a corner it will look for. The `blurRadiusInPixels`, `sensitivity`, and `threshold` can be tweaked at a given resolution to pull out more or fewer corners, but you can also experiment with lowering the resolution of images coming into the detector to have them pick up larger-scale corners. The current implementation is also limited to a max of 256 corners, so if all of these are detected in the upper left of the image, no more will be reported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
filter.cornersDetectedBlock = { (cornerArray:UnsafeMutablePointer<GLfloat>, cornersDetected:UInt, frameTime:CMTime) in
    for index in 0..<Int(cornersDetected) {
        points.append(CGPoint(x:CGFloat(cornerArray[index * 2]), y:CGFloat(cornerArray[(index * 2) + 1])))
    }
}
```

This code you have here sets a block that gets called every frame.

This is an asynchronous process so when your function returns that has never been called yet and your array *should* always be empty. It should be called after the frame has finished processing.

To verify this, set a breakpoint inside that block and see if it gets called.

**Warning from Brad Larson (creator of GPUImage) in the comments:**

The GPUImage you create here `stillImageSource` will be deallocated after this function exits and may cause crashes in this case.

Comment: Yes, this is true. I actually tried printing the points from inside the for loop at one point, however the filter fails to detect corners in the test image I was using, so I missed that.

Comment: Technically, this is called after any processed frame, whether or not corners were detected. You're right that GPUImagePicture's -processImage method fires a processing job on a background dispatch queue, which most likely won't complete before this function exits. That also means that the GPUImagePicture defined locally in this function will be deallocated before the processing is completed, which can lead to crashes if you're not careful. I had a synchronous version of this operation once, but don't remember why I removed it. Deadlocks, maybe?

Comment: Thanks for dropping by with some clarification @BradLarson! I've updated with some info you provided. :]